# Difference between manipulate and sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

I recently started doing some work with shiny, and I realised that both `manipulate` (from library `manipulate`) and `sliderInput` (from library `shiny`) seemed to do the same thing. Are there any functional differences between the two?

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to `sliderInput` from shiny. I haven't heard of `manipulate` before and it looks like it's very basic and undocumented and doesn't have very much in it, while `shiny` is a complete framework with huge support.  From the tiny bit of documentation I can see, it looks like `manipulate` is meant to be used within RStudio in order to manipulate values on a plot. `sliderInput` is much more powerful than that.

If you look at the development of `manipulate` [on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/manipulate/commits/master) you'll see there were only 7 commits and all of them within a couple weeks about 6 months ago. It doesn't look like it's under active development. The fact that it offers no README or much documentation tells me that it's not really meant to be used (at least not yet).  Unless you know that you need to use `manipulate`, stick with `shiny` :)

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things:

`manipulate` allows you to have an interactive plot ready to use, useful for an exploratory data analysis. It can be used with RStudio only. In fact it is just a function that allow you to calculate some R code without re-write all the code.

`sliderInput` allows you to add a slider widget object to the user interface of a shiny app. This might be seems easy but in fact it transforms R code into an HTML code that browsers can understand, so nothing to do with manipulate that works only in your R studio. slider input (like all input functions) also has the vital `id` element that allows you to link the user interface with the server side of a shiny app in order to achieve some reactivity because you usually put the "id" paired with a input object that lies inside an output object. As you can see the simple slider allows to link an input (coming from users of the shiny apps) inside an output object, which is rendered by an output function not only based on the underneath R code but with the code plus the input (transformed in R code) given by the slider.